# How to make time machine back up immediately

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, big-sur

I just plugged an external hard drive into a MacBook.

On that MacBook I opened Time Machine.app, turned off "Back Up Automatically", chose the external hard drive as a disk to back up to, clicked through everything, and now underneath the disk in Time Machine it just says "Waiting to back up".

How can I make it actually start the back up? I don't know what it is waiting for (it's been like that for 10 minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because the MacBook wasn't charging.

I plugged it in, but there is also an Option to back up on battery power in Options.

Answer (score 3):

You need to click on "**Stop this backup**" in the menu bar (by clicking on the Time Machine icon <sup>[image]</sup>) if there's an already running backup (just to be sure). Then, once the backup is paused, you can start a backup manually (now), by simply clicking on the Time Machine icon <sup>[image]</sup> in the menu bar and clicking on "**Back Up now**".

[image: image from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250]

See [Back up your Mac with Time Machine - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201250#:%7E:text=new%20backup%20instead.-,make%20a%20backup,-Back%20up%20automatically) for more information.